# Is this continuity error in "Jagged Edge" intentional?

Tags: continuity, editing, jagged-edge

1985's *[Jagged Edge](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089360/)* has a continuity error. In the scenes that take place during the first day of the trial, Glenn Close, who plays a defence attorney, is wearing three different outfits while she is giving her opening statement to the jury.

I have always wondered if that was an intentional joke because the error seems so obvious, but I've never been able to find an official story behind how that continuity error made it into the film. Does anyone know if it was intentional or not?

Comment: Is there a youtube link we could see, or is the sequence it too long to fit that type of format? Have to admit it's been so long since I saw it, I absolutely cannot remember the internal timeline vs potential error.

Comment: @Tetsujin I unfortunately couldn't find a video clip of the scene online. In the first courtroom scene she is wearing a different outfit when they cut and then a different outfit when they cut again so it isn't a timeline issue. There are cuts but it is all one scene. I've found it mentioned on IMDB https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089360/goofs?item=gf0834005 and other movie site, but haven't been able to find out if it was an accident or was done as a bit of an inside joke.